# How to show unlimited posts for default post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a Wordpress blog. I want the blog will show unlimited posts in one page. Posts will come from the default post item. I have used the following loop for that.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title();?>
        <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>    

<?php endif; ?>
```

But how can I set here `-1` value for unlimited posts. Also `-1` value not support in admin Reading Settings option. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: What do you mean, unlimited post?

Comment: You want lazy loaded posts I think?

Comment: unlimited post means , all post will show in one page . no pagination in the page

Comment: Pff, for 20.000 posts, you're website will be ... extremly slow.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you, by overriding global `$wp_query`

```
<?php global $wp_query ;
    $args = array('post_per_page' => '-1');
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args) ; // overriding default global of WordPress
?>          

<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_title();?>
                <?php the_content();?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>    
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_postdata();  // Don't forget to add this
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (not tested). I'm not sure about the context of your code snippet but assuming you're instantiating a new WP Query:

```
<?php

$args = ['posts_per_page' => -1];

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Refer to this for "in loop" implementation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop_.28Alternate.29

Make sure to wp_reset_postdata(); to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do it with an Template file and write some custom query to display all post in one page:

like this:

Create a Template file

```
<?php
/* Template Name: All post
*/

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1)
$allpost = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $allpost as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Now in admin select this template file to any page you want to display all post ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution .

```
 $my_args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'paged' => $paged
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $my_args );


if($my_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts() ) :  $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title();?>
            <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```